# Is there a SHA-256 value which hashes to itself?

Tags: hash, sha-256, sha-2

Getting curious about SHA-256 cycles (what happens if you hash a value repeatedly), I came across this question:

[Cycles in SHA256](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24623/cycles-in-sha256?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The first answer suggests that using a 7-bit hash, it's possible to find a value that hashes to itself. See the red dot which isn't part of a loop but on its own:

[image: 7 bit SHA256 hashing]

I assume from the diagram, this means if I apply the 7-bit hashing function to this value, the output matches the input. So my question is if such values are possible in SHA-256, and if anyone knows what value(s) hash to themselves or has ever found one of those values.

Comment: Also relevant: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48580

Comment: Short answer to exactly the question you asked: yes, there's a pretty good chance that a SHA-256 fixed point exists, but no, nobody has ever published one and probably never will without also announcing a major breakthrough in cryptanalysis.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies guys. I didn't know this was called a "fixed point" and it seems like the answer is available by merging both of those linked questions. Hopefully, my answer makes sense to bring everything together.

Answer (score 1):

This question here gives the probability of such a value, called a "fixed point" existing as 63% (based on assuming a "random" property of SHA256):

[Cryptographic hash where the hashing function input is similar to the result](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68431/cryptographic-hash-where-the-hashing-function-input-is-similar-to-the-result)

There is at least one such "fixed point" of the compression function that the SHA256 algorithm uses. An example is here:

[Fixed point of the SHA-256 compression function](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48580/fixed-point-of-the-sha-256-compression-function)

As explained in that answer, "[e]asy to find fixed-points are a known property of this construction", therefore this isn't a problem.

Comment: The "63%" probability assumes SHA-256 is a "random function"; however SHA-256 is not proven to be random (whatever that means); it may show nonrandom characteristics we don't know about.

Comment: It is not a fixed point of SHA-256 it is a fixed point of the compression function that SHA-256 uses.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. Hopefully, it's accurate now.